# Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I get the "Runtime error '1004' Application-defined or object defined" error when I'm trying to run the code below. Been trying to fix it now for a couple of hours, but can't seem to get it right.

What I'm trying to do: Two worksheets, one with Projects and other with all the Perks related to each Project. So on the Perks sheet there can be multiple rows with the same project_id, while on the Project sheet the project_id's are all unique. I want to get a range of data on the rows with the same project_id on Perks sheet to be placed next to each other on the one row of the same project_id on the Projects sheet. Hope you are still following what I mean ;). The code I'm using below works fine on other workbooks with similar situations, so not sure what the problem is here. There are about 3000 entries on the Perks worksheet, so that shouldn't be the problem I think. Any thoughts?

```
   Sub Perks_and_Projects()
    Dim r As Long, lr As Long
    Dim src As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Perks")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 2 To lr
        Set src = Sheets("Projects").Columns(1).Find(.Cells(r, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not src Is Nothing Then
*'error occurs on the next line:*        
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 19).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 20).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 21).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 22).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 23).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Range("AA" & src.Row).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 24).Value
        End If
        Next r
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error occuring?

Comment: Ah, sorry forgot to mention that. I included a comment in the code to indicate where the error occurs.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on that line. What are the values of `src` and its `.Row` property?

Comment: Additionally, why not dim src as range?

Comment: Error still occurs when dimming it as range, value of src seems to be 112766, which might be the problem. value of src.row is 2, so that's fine I'd say.

Comment: Would anyone have any idea what such a high value for src would indicate? I'm still unable to solve the problem I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to create a workaround. Here is the code if anyone runs into a similar situation:

```
Sub Perks_and_Projects()
Dim b As Variant, r As Long, lr As Long, n As Long
Dim src As Object, d As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Perks")
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    b = .Range("A1:B" & lr)
    For r = 1 To lr
        Set src = Sheets("Projects").Columns(1).Find(.Cells(r, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        d = Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If Not src Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Cells(r, 19).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 2).Value = .Cells(r, 20).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 3).Value = .Cells(r, 21).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 4).Value = .Cells(r, 22).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 5).Value = .Cells(r, 23).Value
        Sheets("Projects").Cells(src.Row, d).Offset(0, 6).Value = .Cells(r, 23).Value
    End If
    Next r
End With
Sheets("Perks").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(b, 1), UBound(b, 2)) = b
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```